# Video streaming sharepoint foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, iis

I have IIS Media Services 4.1 on my Windows 2008 R2 machine and I want to make video streaming on my Sharepoint foundation site. Let me know how can I do that using IIS Media Services?

or is there any other way of doing that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box way, you need a custom player.  Look at the Smooth Streaming SDK on MSDN, there are examples for .net and javascript clients.